# How to deserialize an object persisted class has less attributes in class and new class has extra attributes

Tags: java, serialization

```
Persisted class has 
Class A {  boolean x; boolean y; } 

New Class

Class A {  boolean x;  boolean y;  boolean z; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In classes has "serialVersionUID". If you do not set this variable in class, Java will generate it automatically:

You need to know this variable in an already serialized object. And after you can set this value in new class:

```
class A {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = [value_from_old_class];
//...
```